# How to detect browser and show message without javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Ok so my site doesn't work correctly in Internet Explorer unless the user clicks "Allow Blocked Content" upon first visit. Now I came up with some javascript that detects the browser that the webpage is opened in and makes a pop up that reads: 'You are in Internet Explorer. Please allow running scripts and ActiveX controls by clicking "Allow Blocked Content" at the bottom of the page upon reload. Otherwise the site may not work correctly.' BUT it IS a script itself SO the user can only see it if they push it. Right now it's useless because it tells the user to click the button only after they've allowed it. 
My JS is:

```
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'; 
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode; 
if(isChrome === false && isSafari === false && isFirefox === false && isOpera === false)
    {alert('You are in Internet Explorer. Please allow running scripts and ActiveX controls by clicking "Allow Blocked Content" at the bottom of the page upon reload. Otherwise the site may not work correctly.'
);};
```

I need a way to detect the browser and display the message without any JS or JQuery. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: shouldn't you fix the content protocols? Nobody will go into their browser settings to do what you want...they will just leave your site if it isn't working

Comment: IE conditional comments might help, or you could use some special media querys like: @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active)

Comment: @axel.michel IE conditionals aren't supported above IE9

Comment: @charlietfl I know, but for IE9 you can use mediaqueries and below the conditional comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Display a text on the site for every user and hide it with JavaScript, so only the users without JavaScript enabled still see it. With this approach, every user (also in other browsers than IE) sees it, so it should be more general.

HTML:

```
<div id="js-message">You don't have JavaScript enabled, please enable it.</div>
```

JavaScript (on page load):

```
$(function() {
     $('#js-message').remove();
});
```

Comment: Use a `<noscript>` tag ...even simpler

Comment: creative solution! That's great because it'll show on all browsers blocking JS! Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl There are some concerns using `<noscript>` http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/a/noscriptnomore.htm

Answer (score 0):

Move the javascript into the head tag above where you load the ActiveX control and call the alert function there:

```
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1) {
    alert('You are in Internet Explorer...');
}
```

If that doesn't work, put the message in a div at the top of the page in bold and hide it:

```
<div id="ienotice">You are in Internet Explorer...</div>

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('ienotice').style.display = 'none';
}, (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1) ? 5000 : 0);
```