# Script for a web link to try two mirror links and if the first times out, opens the second one instead?

Tags: javascript, browser, hyperlink, timeout, href

For context, the problem I'm facing is that our business still has to use Internet Explorer 11 for some of our stuff. As a result, loads of people are trying to open newer sites (like mine) which are only accessible on newer browsers like Edge and Chrome. I have not accommodated for IE when building because it will be phased out completely from our business in the next 6 months.

I've tried to force users to open the link (to my site) in Edge, by using the link href `edge-browser:http://google.co.uk/` however the problem with this is that if the user is already using Edge browser, Edge doesn't recognise the `edge-browser:` prefix and the link just times out! Very infuriating.

I'm wondering if anyone has a work-around, or whether there might be a way to script a button that tries the Edge link first and if it times out after 3-4 seconds, reverts to the second link instead? What about if there is a way of detecting which browser the user is using, and only showing them the appropriate link? I've trialed having two links present but our employees don't understand the difference or which link to press, and are complaining that the formatting of the site is all wrong when accessing via IE.

Let me know what you think - sorry, I am not very tech-savvy when it comes to browsers.

Comment: Why do you have to support IE11 when all employees have Edge? Show an information page with "This website doesn't support IE11. Use a modern browser".

Comment: @jabaa Unfortunately we have a number of applications that currently only work in IE 11, and the platform we use is still defaulting to using IE 11 for everything (to avoid compatibility issues with the aforementioned systems) unless the user specifically opts to open a different browser, hence the problem I'm facing with my site. Hopefully this makes more sense. It will only be a problem for another 6 months or so, as we replace our systems but in the meantime I'm trying to make the experience for the end-users of my site as seamless as possible.

Comment: As far as I understand, every user has Edge. Why does my first comment not work for you? That's how many other companies solved this problem. It's a quick fix for a temporary problem.

Comment: I've managed to apply some JavaScript [from another Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058437/how-to-detect-browser-and-show-message-without-javascript) that detects the browser, and if IE is being used, alerts the user via an 'alert' that this site is not compatible with IE. 
I was hoping for a more high-tech solution (and ideally to remove the two button link access options) as I know users will still be able to access the IE version which is a complete mess, but this is better than nothing at this stage.